# Node.js Heroku Facebook Developer

Tags: node.js, facebook, heroku, sdk, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have managed to successfully implement a 'log in using Facebook' button in to my website/heroku app, it works fine when used locally with the site URL and App Domain set to localhost:8080 within the app settings of the Facebook development page.

I have now tried to push the app to heroku to go live, I have changed the Site URL and App Domain to *myapp*.herokuapp.com, I have set my heroku config using: 
`heroku config:set FACEBOOK_APP_ID=133333333463066 \ FACEBOOK_SECRET=a7244e333333333a7a2bf9492a6089a0`but whenI attempt to use the button I receive this response:

> Given URL is not permitted by the Application configuration: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not permitted by the App's settings. It must
>   match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain
>   of one of the App's domains.

Comment: Sounds like you need to register your domain `myapp.herokuapp.com` in your Facebook App settings. Try adding a new 'website' platform and put in the new url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was using:

```
module.exports = {

    'facebookAuth' : {
        'clientID'      : '663072463821834', // your App ID
        'clientSecret'  : 'fb87ad1ac64364e3bf42c95766a50e08', // your App Secret
        'callbackURL'   : 'http://infinite-scrubland-4586.herokuapp.com/auth/facebook/callback'
    }
```

to set my config and I hadn't updated my callbackURL with the appropriate suffix of `/auth/facebook/callback`.